# g++ error when trying to run from another file

Tags: c++

I have three files (see code below), one class in `testingMatrix.h`, `testingMatrix.cpp` and one `mainMatrix.cpp`. I want to use the matrix in the file `mainMatrix.cpp`, but it doesn't seem to work, I keep getting an error (I want to combine more files later, but the error is the same for this example);

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "Matrix::Matrix(int, int, double const&)", referenced from:
>         _main in mainMatrix-bd8935.o
>     "Matrix::printMatrix() const", referenced from:
>         _main in mainMatrix-bd8935.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

When I write `g++ testingMatrix.cpp`, `./a.out`, I get a correct print. However, when I write `g++ mainMatrix.cpp`, `./a.out`, I get the error stated above. I've looked around in the forum but can't seem to find a solution for my particular issue.

The first file;

```
//mainMatrix.cpp
#include "testingMatrix.h"

int main(){
    const double value = 3.0;
    int rows = 3;
    int columns = 3;
    Matrix testing(rows, columns, value);
    testing.printMatrix();
}
```

The second file;

```
//testingMatrix.h
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Matrix{
    private:
        int the_rows;
        int the_columns;
        std::vector<std::vector<double> > the_matrix;

    public:
        Matrix(int rows, int cols, const double& value);
        void printMatrix() const;
};
```

The third file;

```
//testingMatrix.cpp
#include "testingMatrix.h"
#include <vector>

Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols, const double& value){
    the_rows = rows;
    the_columns = cols;
    the_matrix.resize(the_rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < the_matrix.size(); i++){
        the_matrix.at(i).resize(the_columns, value);
    }
}

void Matrix::printMatrix() const{
    std::cout << "Matrix: " << std::endl;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < the_rows; i++) {
        std::cout << "[";
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < the_columns; j++) {
            if (j==the_columns-1){
                std::cout << the_matrix.at(i).at(j);
            }
            else{
                 std::cout << the_matrix.at(i).at(j) << ", ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    Matrix testing(3, 3, 3.0);
    testing.printMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You need to compile/link both .cpp files together. But also make sure there is only one main() function.

Comment: @rustyx oh that was the problem, I had checked that solution but I didn't realize I could only have one main() function. thanks man!

Comment: Note the **warnings**, `testingMatrix.cpp:9, 16, 18 & 19 - "warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]"` Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS (`cl.exe`) and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. Example `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c++11 -Ofast testingMatrix.cpp -o mainMatrix mainMatrix.cpp`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to use that.

Comment: @armara I find `-Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls` to be incredibly useful at enforcing sanity (every external function pre-declared exactly once, in the appropriate header, otherwise use `static` or something)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile *and* link your sources...

```
g++ -o mainMatrix testMatrix.cpp mainMatrix.cpp
```

or

```
g++ -c testMatrix.cpp
g++ -c mainMatrix.cpp
g++ -o mainMatrix testMatrix.o mainMatrix.o
```